# Options for elderly Korean woman whose son has abandoned her

Tags: civil-legal-system, republic-of-korea

This question is specific to The Republic of Korea (commonly called South Korea).

An elderly Korean woman is estranged from her financially successful son.  She is impoverished, with minimal income.

It appears that her son's income is considered for the purposes of government assistance.

Does she have any legal options?

Comment: Legal options for accomplishing what?  I'm assuming you want to ask whether she can legally force her son to provide for her or similar, but you need to make that explicit.

Comment: Most likely legal options to stop having the government consider her son's income.  I'd be surprised to find out that there would be a way to force her son to support her.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if either a legal duty to support existed, or if there was an exception to government assistance qualification for estranged children, or both, but I have no way to find out.